# BadRequest on 'Update autoscale settings' in ARM template deployment

Tags: azure

I'm trying to apply scaling settings to an availability set in a templated deployment. I've not been able to find any complete examples of this particular use case in the azure-quickstart-templates to compare against, and the error for incorrect syntax is an uninformative 'BadRequest' with no other information.

Here's my autoscale settings from the template (which otherwise deploys fine)...

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
    "dependsOn": [
        "Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/workersas"
    ],
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "name": "workersscaling",
    "properties": {
        "enabled": true,
        "name": "workersscaling",
        "profiles": [
            {
                "capacity": {
                    "default": 2,
                    "maximum": 4,
                    "minimum": 2
                },
                "name": "Default",
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "metricTrigger": {
                            "metricName": "Percentage CPU",
                            "metricNamespace": "",
                            "metricResourceUri": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets', 'workersas')]",
                            "operator": "GreaterThan",
                            "statistic": "Average",
                            "threshold": 80.0,
                            "timeAggregation": "Average",
                            "timeGrain": "PT1M",
                            "timeWindow": "PT10M"
                        },
                        "scaleAction": {
                            "cooldown": "PT10M",
                            "direction": "Increase",
                            "type": "ChangeCount",
                            "value": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "metricTrigger": {
                            "metricName": "Percentage CPU",
                            "metricNamespace": "",
                            "metricResourceUri": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets', 'workersas')]",
                            "operator": "LessThan",
                            "statistic": "Average",
                            "threshold": 40.0,
                            "timeAggregation": "Average",
                            "timeGrain": "PT1M",
                            "timeWindow": "PT10M"
                        },
                        "scaleAction": {
                            "cooldown": "PT10M",
                            "direction": "Decrease",
                            "type": "ChangeCount",
                            "value": "1"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "targetResourceUri": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets', 'workersas')]"
    },
    "type": "microsoft.insights/autoscalesettings"
}
```

Does anyone have any insights? I've constructed this based on the [response format found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931946.aspx) and autoscaling examples for the web sites service found in the quickstart library.

EDIT:

A little more information having experimented with the Azure CLI tool...

```
~/ $ azure insights metrics definition list /subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/snrg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/workersasinfo:    Executing command insights metrics definition list
+ Querying ""
error:   No registered resource provider found for location 'northeurope' and API version '2014-04-01' for type 'availabilitySets'. The supported api-versions are '2014-12-01-preview, 2015-05-01-preview, 2015-06-15'. The supported locations are 'eastus, eastus2, westus, centralus, southcentralus, northeurope, westeurope, eastasia, southeastasia, japaneast, japanwest'.
```

Perhaps what I'm trying to do simply isn't possible at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure PowerShell module doesn't yet support direct configuration of Azure Autoscale properties, so we'll want to leverage a combination of Azure PowerShell and the Azure Service Management REST API operations for Autoscaling.  The REST API provides operations for adding, deleting, updating and retrieving Autoscale configurations.

Ref: http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2015/02/16/automating-azure-autoscale-via-powershell-and-rest-api.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2015/07/20/managing-azure-resources-with-azure-resource-manager-arm-and-powershell.aspx

Hope this helps you.

Girish Prajwal

Comment: Thanks. The first post you linked to applies to service mode, so I don't believe is suitable for my requirements? The second doesn't cover auto scaling. Also note I'm using the node.js-based Azure CLI tool and ARM JSON templates rather than using PowerShell. What I really need is an example of an ARM mode template block that applies autoscaling to an availability set, which I've not been able to find so far.

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems in you template. Here's one that works. Remember that you need S1 App Service plan at minimum to see autoscale:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "serverFarmName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "capacityDefault": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "1"
        },
        "capacityMinimum": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "1"
        },
        "capacityMaximum": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "10"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-04-01",
            "name": "[parameters('serverFarmName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/autoscalesettings",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "profiles": [
                    {
                        "name": "Default",
                        "capacity": {
                            "default": "[parameters('capacityDefault')]",
                            "maximum": "[parameters('capacityMaximum')]",
                            "minimum": "[parameters('capacityMinimum')]"
                        },
                        "rules": [
                            {
                                "metricTrigger": {
                                    "metricName": "CpuPercentage",
                                    "metricNamespace": "",
                                    "metricResourceUri": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('serverFarmName'))]",
                                    "timeGrain": "PT1M",
                                    "statistic": "Max",
                                    "timeWindow": "PT5M",
                                    "timeAggregation": "Average",
                                    "operator": "GreaterThan",
                                    "threshold": 45
                                },
                                "scaleAction": {
                                    "direction": "Increase",
                                    "type": "ChangeCount",
                                    "value": "2",
                                    "cooldown": "PT5M"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "metricTrigger": {
                                    "metricName": "MemoryPercentage",
                                    "metricNamespace": "",
                                    "metricResourceUri": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('serverFarmName'))]",
                                    "timeGrain": "PT1M",
                                    "statistic": "Max",
                                    "timeWindow": "PT5M",
                                    "timeAggregation": "Average",
                                    "operator": "GreaterThan",
                                    "threshold": 75
                                },
                                "scaleAction": {
                                    "direction": "Increase",
                                    "type": "ChangeCount",
                                    "value": "2",
                                    "cooldown": "PT5M"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "metricTrigger": {
                                    "metricName": "HttpQueueLength",
                                    "metricNamespace": "",
                                    "metricResourceUri": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('serverFarmName'))]",
                                    "timeGrain": "PT1M",
                                    "statistic": "Max",
                                    "timeWindow": "PT5M",
                                    "timeAggregation": "Average",
                                    "operator": "GreaterThen",
                                    "threshold": 100
                                },
                                "scaleAction": {
                                    "direction": "Increase",
                                    "type": "ChangeCount",
                                    "value": "2",
                                    "cooldown": "PT5M"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "metricTrigger": {
                                    "metricName": "CpuPercentage",
                                    "metricNamespace": "",
                                    "metricResourceUri": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('serverFarmName'))]",
                                    "timeGrain": "PT1M",
                                    "statistic": "Max",
                                    "timeWindow": "PT5M",
                                    "timeAggregation": "Average",
                                    "operator": "LessThan",
                                    "threshold": 15
                                },
                                "scaleAction": {
                                    "direction": "Decrease",
                                    "type": "ChangeCount",
                                    "value": "1",
                                    "cooldown": "PT5M"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "enabled": true,
                "name": "[parameters('serverFarmName')]",
                "targetResourceUri": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('serverFarmName'))]"
            }
        }

    ]
}
```